# IE specific AJAX access issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9, yahoo-pipes

I'm having trouble debugging the AJAX request. (It's `async` because it's a tunnel)

Anyways, it works fine on Chrome and Firefox but fails in IE8/9 at least.

```
var responseA = '';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://pipes.yahooapis.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=xxxxxx&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rottentomatoes.com%2Fm%2Fthe_hunger_games%2F&_render=json',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(text) {
        responseA = text;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});

console.log(responseA);​
```

`errorThrown` throws `LOG: No Transport`

I tried adding `$.support.cors = true;`

to try to fix any cross domain issues but now I get

`LOG: Error: Access is denied.` (only in IE) what gives?

Comment: If you want to use cross-domain AJAX requests, you need to specify a `dataType` of `jsonp` rather than `json`.

Comment: I read that won't work with `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 (and below) do not support CORS, and you have to proxy their requests (via PHP script at the same domain, which calls the remote script and returns the output)